# LG K40 fingerprint sensor repurpose

Tags: pcb

I am attempting to repurpose a slim LG K40 fingerprint sensor for a diy project. I am looking for a small breakout board that connects to it, so I may connect wires to the small pins. It is a 10 pin connector (I believe a PFC) I have searched online, but can only find breakout boards for other wire tapes that don't connect. Any tips?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/WLMHDQg8ZpuEuNM47

Comment: The photos of the sensor

Answer (score 0):

1. Buy a breakout PCB similar to this:. 
   [https://www.amazon.com/10-Pin-Connector-Breakout-Board-0-5mm/dp/B0191ELG4Y?ref_=fsclp_pl_dp_2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0191ELG4Y)
   [image]!
2. Buy another FPC connector of matching pitch. I am assuming it is 0.5mm pitch.

   https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/FH19C-5S-0.5SH-99/H122523CT-ND/5125686

Then you can buy one FPC ribbon cable to connect Both.

[image]

The links are only for examples. 
I would have directly soldered pencil wires on the connector legs of the sensor. The last image is the pencil wire. Which is easy to solder on small pins like the connector.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was I will try this and hope it works out